# What is the best way of generating unique score for a hash

Tags: python, hash

I am trying to write a code, so that it generates a unique score for each hash. Basically I want to return the same node to multiple user if they request same content.

Here is my code:

```
import hashlib
#define nodes
nodes = ["192.168.20.2", "192.168.20.3", "192.168.20.4", "192.168.20.5", "192.168.20.6", "192.168.20.7"]

def selectNodes(clientIP,request):
    hash_list = []
 for node_ips in nodes:
        score = 0
        ready_hash = str(request) + str(node_ips)
        m = hashlib.md5((ready_hash).encode("utf-8"))
        hashed_node = m.hexdigest()
        for char in hashed_node:
            score += int(char, 16)
        hash_list.append((node_ips, score))
    sorted_by_score = sorted(hash_list, key=lambda tup:tup[1], reverse=True)

    (node_ip, score) = sorted_by_score[0]
    return (node_ip, sorted_by_score)
```

If I call:

```
selectNodes("10.10.10.20", "movie1")
```

suppose it returns 192.168.20.2 for movie1. Next time when the same or other user requests for "movie1". It should return the same node 192.168.20.2. I don't want to map the {movies to nodes}. It should compute at runtime and give the correct result.

The above code works fine for me, but sometime the computed score for the nodes becomes same.

What can I do so that it computes unique score for each hash.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, what you mean by "score", or what the relation between the list of IPs and the IP address passed to the function is. Your function doesn't even use `clientIP` anywhere. Please give an explanation with examples.

Comment: can you give example inputs where the md5 was the same?

Comment: I am not saying the hashes are same, but the calculated scores are same. Here is one example >>> selectNodes("10.10.10.20", "movie4") -- Output
('192.168.20.2', [('192.168.20.2', 287), ('192.168.20.5', 287), ('192.168.20.3', 274), ('192.168.20.7', 267), ('192.168.20.6', 242), ('192.168.20.4', 226)]). So we see 192.168.20.2 and 192.168.20.5 have same calculated score. Is there any logic so that I can compute a unique score.

Comment: Using a dict solves all problems with hash collisions. Why don't you want to map the {movies to nodes}?

Comment: These nodes are caching proxy servers. So, when a user get content for movie1 that is proxied to one proxy server. I don't want another user who request for the same movie1 get different server as it is already cached in one of the proxy server. Since, multiple movies gets added and sure to grow exponentially in time I am looking way to avoid  manually populating the dictionary.

Comment: Why not sort the actual hashes, either as ints or strings, instead of sorting score? OTOH, there are better ways to pseudo-randomly associate names to models. I assume you want each of the nodes to have roughly the same odds of being chosen for a given movie name.

Answer (score 2):

A solution to always assign the same node to the same request would be to index the list of nodes with the hash of the request alone (modulo the length of the list).

```
#define nodes
nodes = ["192.168.20.2", "192.168.20.3", "192.168.20.4", "192.168.20.5", "192.168.20.6", "192.168.20.7"]

def selectNodes(request):
    return nodes[hash(str(request)) % len(nodes)]
```

Comment: This is true as long as the number of nodes is constant.

Comment: Works only when the length of node is same, when I increase or decrease I get different result >>> selectNodes("10.10.10.20", "movie55")
('192.168.20.5', -209424909)
>>> 
======================= RESTART
>>> selectNodes("10.10.10.20", "movie55")
('192.168.20.5', -1462240266)
>>> 
======================= RESTART: 
>>> selectNodes("10.10.10.20", "movie55")
('192.168.20.3', 1029891531)

Comment: @Maanish I am not sure what the intended behaviour is when you add a node to the list. All possible movies have already been assigned to the existing node, so no movie will be assigned to the new node???

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't depend on nodes order, but may change output if a new node will be added to list.

```
import random


def compute_hash(a, b):
    return hash("%s:%s" % (a, b))


def select_node(request, nodes):
    hashes = [
        [compute_hash(request, x), x]
        for x in nodes
    ]
    return max(hashes)[-1]


def test_select_node():
    nodes = [
        "192.168.20.2",
        "192.168.20.3",
        "192.168.20.4",
        "192.168.20.5",
        "192.168.20.6",
        "192.168.20.7",
    ]
    request = "movie1"

    # remember the first result
    node = select_node(request, nodes)

    for _ in range(3):
        # the order changes, but the result remains the same
        random.shuffle(nodes)
        assert select_node(request, nodes) == node
```